# I am trying to start a Spark Session in Jupyter Notebook and get the following error

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark

This is my first time using PySpark.
I am using a Mac and I am trying to start up a session within Jupiter Notebook using the code below:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
```

The error message I get is:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x15fef0a0) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x15fef0a0 [in thread "Thread-2"]
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
    ... 19 more
```

I have installed Java and set `JAVA_HOME` using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gdpclEE-kA

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You also need set:

```
SPARK_HOME="YOUR SPARK PATH"
```

Also consider:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin:$SPARK_HOME/bin
```